# Only match if it starts with characters

Tags: regex

I have this regex to match with image URLs in HTML code:

```
$regex = '#[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)#iu';
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNYLJd/1)

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/0hdkb):

```
$input = <<<HTML
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example1.jpg">
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/ストスト.jpg">
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example3.jpg">
<a href="https://e...content-available-to-author-only...e.com/example3.bak">
HTML;

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($input, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
$regex = '#^[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$#iu';

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $res = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    if (preg_match($regex, $res)) {
        echo "Valid url: $res" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Invalid url: $res" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I make it only match if it starts with `http` or `//`. Currently it matches with `example.jpg` which isn't a full URL.

Comment: `$regex = '#^(?:http|//)[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$#iu';`? BTW, maybe `[\w,=/:.-]+` can be just replaced with `.*` - do you really need to validate that part, too?

Comment: Just add `http` at the beginning: `http[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)` or `(?:http|\/\/)[\w,=/:.-]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)` . [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNYLJd/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you post an answer with this? Also, if you have a suggestion on improving the current regex (as you highlighted in your comment). Basically, if there is one soul out there who I would trust with regex magic, it would be you.

Comment: Well, the question is about matching either `http` or `//` at the start of the string, and that is `^(?:http|//)`, there are no further requirements in your question. If you need to ask for improvement, you should probably post at [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

Matching either `http` or `//` at the start of the string can be done with `^(?:http|//)` t hat you need to add at the start. To make sure the URL ends with the extensions you specified you need to add `$` at the end.

Since you obtain the URL string from a tag attribute using `$anchor->getAttribute("href")` you do not need to validate the inner text of the URL, I suggest replacing `[\w,=/:.-]+` with `.*` to match any text in between.

So, you may use

```
$regex = '#^(?:http|//).*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$#iu';
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:http|//)` -`http` or `//`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `\.`  - a `.` char
- `(?:jpe?g|png|gif)` - `jpeg`, `jpg`, `png` or `gif` strings
- `$` - end of string.

If you want it to work with the HTML text, you need to use

```
$regex = '#\bhref=(["\']?)((?:http|//)[^"\']*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))\1#iu';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $txt, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[2]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ufGu5k/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `href=` - literal text
- `(["\']?)` - Group 1: `"` or `'` captured in Group 1
- `((?:http|//)[^"\']*\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))` - Group 2:

  - `(?:http|//)`  - `http` or `//`
  - `[^"\']*` - 0+ chars other than `'` and `"`
  - `\.` - a `.`
  - `(?:jpe?g|png|gif)` - extension string
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1, either `"` or `'` or empty.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest such pattern: `href="((?:http|\/\/)[^"]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))"`

**Explanation:**

`href="` - match `href="` literally, it will assure that you'll match hyperlink

`(...)` - capturing group to store actual link

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`http|\/\/` - match `http` or `//`

`[^"]+` - match 1+ of any characters other from `"`

`\.` - match `.` literally

`jpe?g|png|gif` - alterantion, match onne of the options `jpeg`, `jpg` (due to `e?`), `png`, `gif`

`"` - match `"` literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vNYLJd/3)

Matched link will be inside 1st capturing group.

Comment: `href=` can't be matched as OP parses HTML with `DOMDocument` and the string tested against the regex is already the `href` value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The DOMDocument approach was only a test. I do match with full HTML code in strings as well.

Comment: I presume the PHP version of this regex is: `$re = '@href="((?:http|\/\/)[^"]+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif))"@mu';`